# 500 Внутренняя ошибка сервера

Tags: php, apache

У меня есть скрипт opencase (Сайт Магазина кейсов CSGO). Я загрузил сайт на сервер ([default page](http://devildrop.ru)). При входе на сайт выдается ошибка:

> 500 Внутренняя ошибка сервера.

В логах apache пишется:

> AH00124 request exceeded the limit of 10.

Как это исправить?
Мой .htaccess:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^case/(.*) index.php?module=case&name=$1 [R]
RewriteRule ^user/(.*) index.php?module=user&id=$1 [R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?module=$1 [L,QSA]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
 RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Все Rule должны быть после Cond. И флаг `L(ast)` нужно ставить на всех оконечных правилах

Comment: @vp_arth, `Все Rule должны быть после Cond.` не обязательно.